# From a named range, select one column but not the header row

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, named-ranges

I can make this work for a whole column, but if I have a NamedRange, I'll call food as follows.

| Vegetables | Fruit | Meat |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Carrot | Apple | Pork |
| Potato | Orange | Chicken |
| Turnip | Pear | Beef |

Then I want to grab the column below the first row and then add that to a drop-down.

I know how to populate the drop-down, and I can grab a whole column using Map, but how do I get just the items below the first row.

---

I've created the following working script, but when you Logger.log (oneSet)

I get the whole column, including the heading. Instead, I want the relevant column of data without the heading.

```js
function selectCol(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var foodList = ss.getRangeByName("Food").getValues();

var oneSet = foodList.map(oneCol);

function oneCol(one){
      return one[2]
    };
Logger.log(oneSet);

// [0] returns [Vegetables, Carrot, Potato, Turnip]
// [1] returns [Fruits, Apple, Orange, Pear]
// [2] returns [Meats, Pork, Chicken, Beef]

// So what I want is:
// [0] to return [Carrot, Potato, Turnip]
// [1] to return [Apple, Orange, Pear]
// [2] to return [Pork, Chicken, Beef]

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This function builds all three and places them right below each list.

```
function makeADropDown() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const vs = sh.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  [...Array.from(Array(3).keys())].forEach(idx => {
    let r =SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(sh.getRange(2,idx + 1,sh.getLastRow()-1,1)).build();
    sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow() + 1,idx + 1).setDataValidation(r);
  })
}
```

[image]

This line just creates and array like [0,1,2] to run through the loop 3 times.

`[...Array.from(Array(3).keys())]`

Comment: Thank you Cooper for your help.I was hoping to use the Named Range rather than using row columns. I found that I could move and add to a named Range and the script would not break. Whereas the alternative needed to know the first row and column cell, if that moved the script failed.